# How to authenticate redhat user against ldap/MS AD

Tags: linux, authentication, ldap

As the title.

I have 10 linux servers, each of these servers have same username and password. So I am thinking manage user credentials just like windows servers.

However I read through redhat online document and search through google. All the solutions provided are difficult to implement.  My question is, what's the easiest way to manage my user account in a centralised place.

Comment: This question is off topic here, and should be migrated to serverfault.com, but it can't be due to bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I integrate my ubuntu machines with AD as mentioned in the below link :

[Authenticate Ubuntu machines using Windows Active Directory](https://gopukrish.wordpress.com/2015/04/08/integrate-linux-machine-with-ad/)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing for you to do is, install and use NIS server for central authentication. This post contains a how-to http://bradthemad.org/tech/notes/redhat_nis_setup.php.

Comment: Seems like NIS server is not a common practise for Enterprise solutions.  And NIS solution is dying everywhere after I do a search on Internet.

Comment: Correct, but in his case NIS suits him the most. Easy and simple

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are searching for pam_ldap.